# Nature of the differential Equation $2ydx -(3y -2x)dy =0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Differential equation

$2ydx -(3y - 2x)dy= 0$ is :

(a)Exact,Homogenous But not Linear

(b)Homogeneous and Linear but not Exact.

(c) Exact and Linear but not homogeneous

(d) Exact homogeneous and Linear.

Now I have verified that this equation is exact and homogeneous

Also this equation can be written as:

$2ydx = (3y -2x)dy$ and thus ,

$dx /dy = 3/2 - x /y$ and clearly this is an Linear Differential Equation of the form

$dx/dy + Px = Q$,

so option (d) must be correct.

However my book says option (a) is correct implying the equation is not Linear.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my solution ?

Thank You.

Comment: @Moo: Well, the given Equation cannot be written in this form,because I cannot separate the variables. Is this the reason due to which the equation is Not Linear ?

Answer (score 0):

Writing
$$-\frac{1}{2}y'(x)(-2x+3y(x))+2y(x)=0$$
making the substitution
$$y(x)=xv(x)$$
then we get
$$-\frac{1}{2}(-2x+3xv(x))(xv'(x)+v(x))+2xv(x)=0$$
then you will obtain
$$\frac{dv(x)}{dx}=-\frac{3(v(x)^2-2v(x))}{x(3v(x)-2)}$$
Last step
$$\int \frac{v'(x)(3v(x)-2)}{(v(x)-2)v(x)}dx=\int-\frac{3}{x}dx$$